# Which model should I use in R?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I have a dataset consists of 22 variables with 1424410 observations.
The dependent variable is tripprice which is numeric.
The independent variables is categorized and I have converted them into factors with 2 - 8 levels. Example; Passengersize consists of 8 levels. Small group, medium group and large group consists of 2 levels which is 1 or 0 for presence. I've also got daytime, eveningtime, othertime which also is 2 levelse.

I've tried to run a multinominal logistic regression, but couldnt get the results with glm because of the dependent variable is like numeric "2000" "153" and not a factor variable. 
I understand that I use glm when the dependent variable is categorical and the independent variables is continous? And the same for when the dependent and independent variables both are categorical that I use logistic regression.
I also tried lm models, but then I've got 2 not defined because of singularities for large group and othertime.....

SO what kind of regression do I use when my dependent variable is "normal numeric observations" and my independent variables is categorized with factor levels?

Dependent variable;
Trip price ("200, 59, 300...")

Independent variables (Every categori got 1 or 0);
Rush morning (2 levels, 1 or 0 for presence or not)
Rush evening (2 levels, 1 or 0 for presence or not)
Day time -"-
Evening time -"-
Other time -"-
Passenger size (8 levels, 1 or 0 for presence or not)
Small group -"-
etc...

---

But When I use lm in R, I've got "2 not defined because of singularities" for the independent variables large group and for othertime? I dont know why, cause I made all the independent variables as factors before I run lm.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open.  Although it's posed in terms of R, it's really about types of regression.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Or at least it is not well described.

Comment: The problem is; Do I use lm, glm or another model. Cause Ive tried everything and something wrong happens everytime.

Comment: It think you should describe the 'something wrong' a little bit better since lm and glm can both fit to many situations, and it is unclear what goes wrong in your case (except that multinomial is obviously wrong for a numerical dependent variable but you can still use numeric dependent variables in glm, so it isn't really the core issue).

Comment: A most simple example would be a numerical dependent variable based on a *single* categorical variable.

For instance the size of a person in a specific group as a function of gender, $$size \sim N(\mu_{gender},\sigma)$$ and you will be measuring $size$ numeric, and $gender$ categorical, but still use 'glm' or 'lm' to model it (without any problems).

You just have more of those independent categorical variables and this is not really a matter of principle. You should explain more about your *practical* errors/problems/wrongs.

Comment: @Ida "Something wrong happens everytime" is a software issue. I suggest creating a reproducible example, and showing the error and output over on StackOverflow.com (browse existing answers first, someone likely already addressed your issue). If you debug your script, it's very much on topic to ask about why you fit those models *here*.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the main problem here is in the use of the computer: somehow numerical data (trip prices) have been formatted as strings, making it impossible to analyze them appropriately.  @Peter Since that doesn't look like a "types of regression" problem, could you elaborate on what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You should at least start with ordinary least squares regression which is available with `lm` in R. Your dependent variable is continuous.

The issue is going to be the categorical variables that are ordinal. There's no really standard approach, but I've gotten some good results with optimal scaling.  However, just treating them as categorical is simpler.